# Are prices random or fixed?

Tags: organ-trail

As I was playing the Organ Trail, I noticed along the journey, prices started to change, mostly going up but occasionally going back down by a few dollars.

Are there fixed prices (or availability) for goods at certain stops, or is it completely random? Also, what is the rate of increase for prices of goods?

Comment: It seems to be based on the availability of goods, but there's also a bit of randomness built into it.

Comment: There's also an range for goods, I don't think I've ever seen medkits cost more than ~38$, for instance or less than ~24$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prices are random within a weighted range. That is, scraps, for example, can vary between $4-$9 (exact numbers are unknown to me), but it might favor $6, and as such, you will be most likely, but not guaranteed, to see prices at $6 or close to that on scraps. I have yet to determine myself whether it is based in any degree on the availability of the goods.

Comment: medkits *seems* to be cheaper when there are lots of them, but that could just be confirmation bias at work.

Comment: It seems likely and reasonable for the prices to be lower when there's an abundance of them. I'll look into it a little when I get home.

Comment: If the prices are based on abundance/quantity, then my next question would be, is quantity random or fixed for certain stops? I've certainly noticed that certain locations like the abandoned shack or whatever rarely have things for sale, but my sample size is low.

Comment: @bd33 I believe cities generally do have more stuff to sell.  I've played a lot on endless mode and that's from what I've observed.